# Node.Js multer req.file always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

im triying to upload a file with multer but always the req.file is undefined and the destination folder is empty:

**Server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express();

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, './public/uploads/'); // Make sure this folder exists
            },
            filename: function(req, file, cb) {
                            console.log(file)
                var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
                cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
            }
        }),
        upload = multer({
            storage: storage
        }).single('avatar');

    app.post('/uploads', upload, (req, res) => {
        console.log('body', req.body);
        console.log('file', req.file);
                res.json("ok")
    });
```

**Client:**

I've looked at many answers but nothing worked.

```
      <form id="myform" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="userName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="userName"/>
        <br>
        <label for="phoneNumber">PhoneNumber</label>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"/>
        <br>
        <label for="file">UploadFile</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

$('#myForm').submit(function(e){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'uploads',
            data : formData,
            contentType: true,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data){
            //print response on success
            console.log(data);

        }).fail(function(data) {
              console.log('Error');
          });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
```

[image]
Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in the ajax I've to set the content type to false:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'uploads',
            data : formData,
            contentType: false, // <-----------------
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data){
            //print response on success
            console.log(data);

        }).fail(function(data) {
              console.log('Error');
          });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
```

Thanks to @Marc.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you implemented `$('#myForm').submit(function(e){...})`?

You have a typo in your `<form>` element. The attribute is called `enctype`, not "encrypt". And you could simply add the `method="POST"` attribute and remove all javascript and let the browser to the upload.

Sample:

```
<form method="POST" action="/uploads" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 .....
</form>
```

Comment: Your  sample works, thank you so much. Can you tell me how can I catch the response?

Comment: Where do you want to catch it? Do you want the browser to stay on the page with the upload form?

Comment: I would suggest to send a redirect. With express you can take a look here how to do it: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect